# Hosting a bottlepy app in apache (mod-wsgi)

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, web-deployment

I have developed a Python web application using [bottlepy](http://bottlepy.org/). It takes in 7 input parameters and return a JSON string.

```
@route('/aggregation')
def service():
    poi_data = request.GET.get('poi', default=None)
    crime_data = request.GET.get('crime', default=None)
    walkshed_collection = request.GET.get('walkshed_collection', default=None)
    walkshed_union = request.GET.get('walkshed_union', default=None)
    start_point = request.GET.get('start_point', default=None)
    transit_data = request.GET.get('transit', default=None)
    distance_decay_function = request.GET.get('distance_decay_function',    default=None).lower()
    walking_time_period = request.GET.get('walking_time_period', default=None)

    if start_point and poi_data and crime_data and walkshed_collection and walkshed_union and transit_data and distance_decay_function and walking_time_period is not None:
        return aggregation(start_point, poi_data, transit_data, crime_data, walkshed_collection, walkshed_union, distance_decay_function, walking_time_period)


run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9364, debug=True)
```

It works fine with both HTTP GET and POST when I run the application using the bottlepy web server using terminal, like python aggregation.py.

But when I managed to host it in Apache using mod-wsgi, it did not work; the Apache logged "URI Too Long" when using HTTP GET and "caught SIGTERM, shutting down" when using HTTP POST. Actually, some of the inputs are too long JSON strings like poi_data, crime_data, walkshed_collection_walkshed_union, and transit_data. For example, the length of KVP request is around 200KB.

Here is the Apache configuration:

```
Listen *:9364

<VirtualHost *:9364>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1

    WSGIDaemonProcess aggregation user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /aggregation /var/www/aggregation/adapter.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/aggregation>
        WSGIProcessGroup aggregation
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I should mention that I have developed couple of Python web applications that work fine with both bottle web server and Apache mod-wsgi. But they take in small input parameters. So I assume that the problem might be related to the size of request. Do you guys have any idea how I can fix the problem? Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ebrahim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of:

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/modwsgi/8HJhaOleYwA/e29CtXY4_8UJ

Answer provided in the mod_wsgi mailing list.